# Killing mongo queries running more than expected time

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, backend

I would like to kill mongo queries which run more than 15 seconds using python script.

I tried running an aggregation query on db which takes around 50 seconds to execute and then run the python script using the following function but the outcome is different from that of expected.

```
def function():
    queries = client.admin.command("currentOp", {"secs_running": {"$gte": 15}})

    # Iterate through the queries and kill any that have been running for more than 15 seconds
    for query in queries['inprog']:
        print(query)
        client.admin.command({"killOp": 1, "op": query['opid']})

    print("Queries killed: {}".format(len(queries['inprog'])))
    return "Queries killed: {}".format(len(queries['inprog']))
```

The output:

```
'WTCheckpointThread', 'active': True, 'currentOpTime': '2023-01-16T05:12:22.019+00:00', 'opid': 'atlas-1ujy-shard-0:16945254', 'op': 'none', 'ns': '', 'command': {}, 'numYields': 0, 'locks': {}, 'waitingForLock': False, 'lockStats': {}, 'waitingForFlowControl': False, 'flowControlStats': {}}

'conn18976', 'connectionId': 18976, 'client_s': '192.168.241.44:57452', 'appName': 'MongoDB Automation Agent v12.9.1.7908 (git: 77314b2820d1c608a729a42d9990756)', 'clientMetadata': {'driver': {'name': 'mongo-go-driver', 'version': 'v1.10.1-cloud'}, 'os': {'type': 'linux', 'architecture': 'arm64'}, 'platform': 'go1.18.8', 'application': {'name': 'MongoDB Automation Agent v12.9.1.7908 (git: 77314b2820d1bf6611cf8a729a42d9990756)'}}, 'active': True, 'currentOpTime': '2023-01-16T05:12:22.019+00:00', 'opid': 'atlas-1j2y-shard-0:1698686', 'secs_running': 1, 'microsecs_running': 1959001, 'op': 'command', 'ns': 'admin.$cmd', 'command': {'hello': 1, 'helloOk': True, 'topologyVersion': {'processId': ObjectId('63c02256ebe4c02191ee0'), 'counter': 5}, 'maxAwaitTimeMS': 10000, '$db': 'admin', '$readPreference': {'mode': 'primaryPreferred'}}, 'numYields': 0, 'waitingForLatch': {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 16, 5, 12, 20, 160000), 'captureName': 'FutureResolution'}, 'locks': {}, 'waitingForLock': False, 'lockStats': {}, 'waitingForFlowControl': False, 'flowControlStats': {}}

so on....
Queries killed: 34
```

Comment: Wantonly killing anything that has been running longer than 15 seconds could cause a lot of unexpected problems.  Have you tried just setting a timeout on the operations you send?

Comment: The actual problem is people running queries which take longer time to execute causing memory issues. So would like to set a cron for which runs this script for every five minutes and kills queries running for more than 15 minutes. for testing the script I have taken 15 secs.

Comment: You'll really want to filter to make sure you only kill user operations.  Hopefully the server won't let you kill something named `WTCheckpointThread`, but I wouldn't want to risk that.